# What is the order that we should follow, while creating an extension in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, extensions

The question I am sharing here is not about creating an extension, but about the order in which we should proceed.

This question will help a lot of people who want to create extensions. Because whenever we are creating an extension we usually try to check the impact our code has done so far.

So the question here is while creating an extension in magento which file/folder should be created in the order of first to last.

Also the extension I am talking about here, is a basic admin extension, with a tab in header in admin as well.

Comment: It depends. Most of the time we start with creating etc/config.xml and module activation file. This guide will have more info http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf

Comment: @Sukeshini Yes, I am aware of the documentation, but I would like be added here, is that core steps on stack itself, so that the shortest steps should be shared not the entire pdf. That is why I shared an example of just a basic extension.

Comment: I don't think there is a right way of doing it. of course, in order for your module to work you need `app/etc/modules/[Namespace]_[Module].xml` and `app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`. But from there it's your choice. Or for simple CRUD modules you can use a module creator and everything is done at the same time.

Comment: @Marius, Thanks for the comment, and sure Module creator is an excellent piece of and we all respect you for that :). What I wanted to know, or rather wanted to be displayed here a small code of how to proceed, so that even a beginner can understand whats going on with what he is writing, instead of copying and pasting code from documentations/tutorials. I hope my point make sense.

Comment: @TBIInfotech. I wasn't talking about my module creator. I was talking about one in general. There are a lot of them out there, all of them do a nice job and saves you the trouble and boredom of doing the same thing over and over again. but I understand your point. It makes sense. Unfortunately I don't have a procedure for that. I'm not sure that I even know anymore how to create a CRUD module "by hand".

Comment: @TBI Infotech: I just put it as a reference. But the answer to your question is depending on several variables such as the functionality of the module, developer's personal procedure of developing methodology etc. Of course you can't try out the code written so far until you write the module activation file and config.xml. So as my opinion those two files should be the entry point. Rest will depend on the other constraint as I've mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Module Declaration
Create `app/etc/modules/M4U_HelloWorld.xml` and write below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
         <modules>
                <M4U_HelloWorld>
                        <active>true</active>
                        <codePool>local</codePool>
                </M4U_HelloWorld>
         </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2: Module Configuration

```
app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/controllers/IndexController.php

class M4U_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout(array('default'));
     $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

b. Create a Block class

```
app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php
```

class M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  // necessary methods
}

c. create configuration xml in `app/code/local/M4U/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
                <m4u_helloworld>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                </m4u_helloworld>
        </modules>
    <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <rewrite>
         <helloworld>M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld</helloworld>
        </rewrite>
            </helloworld>
     </blocks>

        </global>
       <frontend>
                <routers>
                        <helloworld>
                                <use>standard</use>
                                <args>
                                      <module>M4U_HelloWorld</module>
                                      <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                                </args>
                        </helloworld>
                </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                      <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

Define Frontend Template :

1. Define page layout in `app/design/frontend/M4U/default/layout/helloworld.xml`

N.B: Use default instead of M4U as template location if you use default design packages. Means create file in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <layout version="0.1.0">

        <helloworld_index_index>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="hello" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </helloworld_index_index>

    </layout>
```

1. Create template file `app/design/frontend/M4U/default/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml` and write down

N.B: Use default instead of M4U as template location if you use default design packages. Means create file in app/design/frontend/default/default/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml

Hello World ! I am a Magento Guy..

Hey, new module is ready to run and hit browser with url

```
http://Yourdomain.com/projectname/index.php/helloworld/
```

and see result.

That’s it……..