# Magento custom module blocks and config.xml help

Tags: module, configuration, blocks, magento-1.9

I have created a custom module but having a little difficulty with blocks in the config.xml

For some reason I'm not able to get the blocks to show on the dump of all the xml...maybe I've missed something?

I have the following structure:

app\code\local\Site\SiteTest\etc\config.xml

app\code\local\Site\SiteTest\Block\test.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Site_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Site_Test>
    </modules>  
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <highest>
                <class>Site_Block</class>
            </highest>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I am trying to link this to  a custom layout for example:

```
<block type="sitetest/test" name="home.catalog.product.test" template="catalog/product/test.phtml" after="cms_page">
```

If anyone could shed some light on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: Try following this tutorial:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23629/what-is-the-order-that-we-should-follow-while-creating-an-extension-in-magento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have provided less info about your module I can suggest the following corrections only. Hope it might useful.

1). There are some mis-configurations in your `config.xml` file. See the below code (corrected one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Site_SiteTest><!--use 'Namespace_Module' -->
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Site_Test>
    </modules>  
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <sitetest> <!-- this node can be anything, But as standard use the lowercase name of your module-->
                <class>Site_SiteTest_Block</class><!-- put entire path upto Block folder-->
            </sitetest>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

2). Rename your block class file as `Test.php`

So the block class declaration should be as follow.

```
<?php
class Site_SiteTest_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
//your code here.
}
```

3). Make sure you have written the module activation file in `app/etc/modules` folder. It should be `Site_SiteTest.xml` with the following content.

```
<config>
   <modules>
      <Site_SiteTest>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
      </Site_SiteTest>
   </modules>
</config>
```

4). Make sure the cache is disabled. (go to `System > Cache Management` and select all, then disabled them)

Comment: Thanks a bunch this helped! May have one or two more questions later though :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you :)

Comment: Ok so I now have:

<sitetest>
<class>Site_Test_Block</class>
</sitetest>

Within my ?showConfig=true...however I seem to be having trouble linking this to a custom XML layout.

<block type="test/test" name="test" template="catalog/product/test.phtml" after="cms_page">

Sorry more tests than anything else lol

Comment: The last test would be the .php file so ermm if I have this right....

<block type="modulename/filename">

Comment: Ok I think I've got it sorted however I have been given the following error when loading the page:

Fatal error: Class 'Site_Test_Block_Test' not found in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491

Comment: Nevermind got it! Was a spelling mistake haha